# Native Paid VPN Service

Tags: vpn

I was in a situation where I wanted to use a tunnel-all VPN, and went to Hotspot Shield's site. Much to my dismay, they ship an installer in order to use their service.

Is there a commercial, high-quality VPN service that supports one of the built-in OSX protocols definable in the Network Preference Pane? L2TP over IPSec, PPTP, or Cisco VPN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, [TUAW](http://www.tuaw.com/) had [an article](http://www.tuaw.com/2011/05/03/ask-tuaw-video-edition-vpn-services/) on this subject earlier this month. How I missed it (or didn't remember it) is beyond me.

Due in part to price (as opposed to karmatic's suggestion), and also the features, namely choice of hosting regional, I'm going to sign up for [OverPlay](https://www.overplay.net/).

Answer (score 1):

[vyprVPN](https://www.goldenfrog.com/) is a pretty good paid service. It supports openVPN, L2TP/IPsec and PPTP protocols.

Answer (score 0):

[expressVPN](http://www.linkev.com/?a_fid=clover) or [vyprVPN](https://www.goldenfrog.com/vyprvpn?offer_id=174&aff_id=3008), each is very good, for more good VPN services, visit [this](http://vpnchina.zdhweb.com/p/china-vpn.html) page.